# How can I use EnvInject with ConfigFileProvider in a Jenkins Pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I would like to use configFileProvider in conjunction with envInject to load a Managed File into the `env` vars.

Managed File contents:

```
someEmail:"someemail@somewhere.com"
```

configFileProvidor creates a map (props below):

```
node {
    configFileProvider(
        [configFile(fileId: 'my-managed-file', variable: 'job_settings')]) {
        props = readProperties file: job_settings
        echo "${props}"
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[someEmail:"someemail@somewhere.com"]
```

How do I get this map into the env vars using EnvInject?

I tried the following:

```
load props
```

Which results in a `org.kohsuke.stapler.NoStaplerConstructorException: There's no @DataBoundConstructor on any constructor of class java.lang.String`

I also tried loading the `job_settings` object directly, which does not result in an error, but the variable does not get included in `env`.

```
node {
    configFileProvider(
        [configFile(fileId: 'my-managed-file', variable: 'job_settings')]) {
        load job_settings
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a working approach using targetLocation:

```
node {
    configFileProvider(
        [configFile(fileId: 'my-managed-file', targetLocation: '/path/to/job_settings_dir')]) {
        load '/path/to/job_settings_dir/my-managed-file'
    }
}
```